# MS Access draw table on the report

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

How is it possible to draw a table on MS Access Report without RecordSource?

I need very simple table with black borders, that should be flexible depending on the passed text

```
-----------------------------------
| Header1  |  Header 2  |  Notes  |
-----------------------------------
| Text1    |  Text 2    |  Notes  |
|          |            |  text   |
-----------------------------------
```

There is "Arrange" tab, which contains some table elements, but it's disable.

How to resolve that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: There may be no ways, you can use temporary tables, so you use tables. Or a static table in Report, so meaningless in your case.

Comment: If the report is to have no Record Source, how do you plan to "pass" it the text values?

Comment: Hi Gord, I pass values via VBA code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put textbox control on the Report, then right mouse click on the control, choose Layout->Tabular, in that case you will have a table/grid flexible and Enabled "Arrange" tab. Also you can set up borders of the cells.